# EF 4 - Exception when updating table with timestamp column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I have created the following table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role](
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
   [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
   [TIMESTAMP] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
   [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_ROLES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY].
```

With EF, I created a ste class with timestamp column of type byte[] which is readonly.

I retrieve an object from my db using the datacontext e.g.

```
var roleObject = roleService.getObject(id);
```

now I change the rolename as follows

```
roleObject.Name = "New Name";
roleObject.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

finally I call my repository to persist the object using the following generic method

```
public void PersistUpdatedItem(T entity){
   _ctx.ApplyCurrentValues(typeof (T).Name, entity);
   _ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
   _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note `ctx` is my session object and T is the entity class. At this point I get an exception

> Cannot update Timestamp Column

Can someone please assist me in solving this one.

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Two points:

- You cannot make `Timestamp` property "read only". EF must be able to set that value so the property must have setter and accessibility of the setter must be same as [accessibility defined in the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202780/entity-framework-and-business-objects/5202859#5202859).
- Your `Timestamp` property must be configured with Concurrency Mode Fixed and [StoreGenerated Pattern Coumputed](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/). Both these configurations are defined in properties window in the designer.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the timestamp from your model object.