# How to create strongly-typed entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Reading [this blog post about Primitive Obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession.aspx) I was wondering:

1. How can I create a strongly-typed entity using Entity Framework Code First? (specially regarding mapping these strong types to primitive types in SqlServer)
2. Does that make sense? (I've never found any examples/tutorials on the web with this kind of approach)

Suppose we have an Address entity/class with a strongly-typed Zipcode property [as we can see here](http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/12/dealing-with-primitive-obsession.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited version according to comment:

It make sense but you have never found any example because it is not directly possible with EF code first. Why?

- Because EF doesn't support entities or complex types without default constructor and it cannot use constructor with parameters.
- Because EF doesn't provide any type conversions so EF must map directly to primitive properties.
- Because EF doesn't support properties without setter.

As a workaround you can use private setter and both default constructor (maybe it doesn't have to be public but I didn't try this) and constructor with parameters and correctly map property (at least [with EDMX it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202780/entity-framework-and-business-objects/5202859#5202859)).

Comment: So, I removed the "readonly" keyword from the "_value" field and added a private set to the property "Value" in the Address class and now EF mapped as expected. Question is, how this changes violates the original ideia of primitive obsession?

Comment: So my answer is wrong. I edited my answer to make it reference for others but you should put your solution to separate answer and accept it.

Comment: The change slightly violates the pattern (for example it offers default constructor) but it is needed if you want to follow primitive type encapsulation with EF.

Comment: The default constructor is also private