# Entity Framework and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add validation to my POCO(template) classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128303/how-to-add-validation-to-my-pocotemplate-classes)

Hi all,

I'm using EF4 for Data Modeling and MVC for presentation.
I have my entities defined and i want to use them in conjunction with Html.LabelFor(..) but that last method don't seem to work.
Where can i define my dataannotations? Remember, all my entities are EF generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use the view model pattern and map the entities to view models.  In summary, this involves mapping the data from your data/domain models to a flattened representation which is more compatible with your view, and does not mix your logic-concerns with your presentation concerns.  Your DataAnnotations should go on your View Models.

### Articles On View Models in ASP.NET MVC

These should help you understand how view models can improve your application and how to implement them.

- http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx
- http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx

I also suggest looking into **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)**, an excellent open source tool for automatically mapping your domain model (in this case entity framework classes) to your view model.

Comment: If you do this you run the risk of needing to declare annotations multiple times for the same Entity. I know some people argue that the annotations should not be coupled to the data layer - but personally I disagree as the validation rules for an entity are unlikely to ever change as they are mapped to your database tables and I wouldn't think that it would be the case that you would dynamically update the TYPES of your database columns or the general functionality that a specific column provides to your app

Answer (score 2):

Define your annotations like so:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MetaDataBusiness))]
public partial class Business //Partial class for Entity
{
     //Don't need anything here for annotations to work
}

public class MetaDataBusiness
{
    [DisplayName("Business Id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Business Id is required")]
    [Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Business Id cannot be less than 0")]
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this.  ViewModels make your Entity classes dependent on your UI layer when it should be the other way around.

Comment: @jfar - I suggest you read my comment above! I have my Entities declared in a DataTransfer project and I declare the Metadata in the same project - I mention nothing here about declaring this in the ViewModel! How a developer chooses to layout their project is not in question here.