# Where do you put your validation in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

One common recommended practice in asp.net mvc is that [you should not send your business models to your views](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/).. instead you should create viewmodels specific to each view.

When that is done and you call the ModelState.IsValid method in your controller you are effectively checking the validity of the viewmodel but not the business object.

What is the conventional approach to dealing with this?

```
public class Person
{
public int ID {get; set;};

[Required]
public string Name {get; set;}

[Required]
public string LastName {get; set;}

public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams {get; set;}

}

public class PersonFormViewModel
{

public int ID {get; set;};    


[Required]
public string Name {get; set;}

[Required]
public string LastName {get; set;}

}
```

This is exactly what I have right now but Im not sure if the [Required] attribute should appear on both models or just the ViewModel or just the Business Model.

Any tips on this issue are appreciatedd.

More links to support my claim that it is a common good practice to always use view models.

[How to add validation to my POCO(template) classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128303/how-to-add-validation-to-my-pocotemplate-classes)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: What is your "business model" exactly?

Comment: Person is a class that is tracked by EntityFramework. PersonViewModel is obviously not.. read the blog post I linked to and you will understand the practices Im trying to follow.. hence the question of where should the validation logic go.

Comment: Thanks - sorry, I scanned the article and searched for "business model" within it but no hits.

Comment: Thats probably not the best way to read an article.... anyways. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My preference is to do *input validation on the view models*, and *business validation on the domain models*.

In other words, any data annotations such as required fields, length validation, regex, etc should be done on your view models, and added to the model state when error occurs.

And you'll probably have business/domain rules that rely on more than just a "form", so you should do that either in the domain models (execute the validation after they're mapped back), or with a service layer.

All our models have a method called "Validate", which we call in the services prior to persisting. They throw custom exceptions if they fail business validation, which gets caught by the controller and also added to the model state.

May not be everyone's cup of tea, but it's consistent.

**Example of business validation, as requested:**

Here's an example of a domain model we have, which represents a generic "Post" (question, photo, video, etc):

```
public abstract class Post
{
   // .. fields, properties, domain logic, etc

   public void Validate()
   {
      if (!this.GeospatialIdentity.IsValidForThisTypeOfPost())
         throw new DomainException(this, BusinessException.PostNotValidForThisSpatial.);
   }
}
```

You see there, I am checking against business rules, and throwing custom exceptions. `DomainException` is our base, and we have many derived implementations. We have an enum called `BusinessException`, which contains values for all our exceptions. We use extension methods on the enum to provide the resource-based error message.

This is not simply a field on the model I'm checking, e.g "All posts must have a subject", because although that is part of the domain, it's input validation first and foremost, and thus is handled via the data annotations on the view model.

Now, the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(QuestionViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     return View(viewModel);

   try
   {
      // Map to ViewModel
      var model = Mapper.Map<QuestionViewModel,Question>(viewModel);

      // Save.
      postService.Save(model); // generic Save method, constraint: "where TPost: Post, new()".

      // Commit.
      unitOfWork.Commit();

      // P-R-G
      return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.PostId });
   }
   catch (Exception exc) 
   {
      var typedExc = exc as DomainException;

      if (typedExc != null)
      {
         // Internationalised, user-friendly domain exception, so we can show
         ModelState.AddModelError("Error", typedExc.BusinessError.ToDescription());
      }
      else
      { 
         // Could be anything, e.g database exception - so show generic msg.
         ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Sorry, an error occured saving the Post. Support has been notified. Please try again later.");
      }
   }

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

So, by the time we get to the "Save" method on the service, the model has passed *input validation*. Then the Save method calls `post.Validate()`, invoking business rules.

If an exception is raised, the controller catches it and displays the message. If it gets pass the Save method and another error occurs (90% of the time, it's Entity Framework, for example), we show a generic error message.

As I said, not for everyone, but this works well for our team. We have a clear separation of presentation and domain validation, and a consistent flow of control from the raw HTTP POST, to the redirect after success.

Comment: would you mind posting a small example of this? especially the controller method.

Comment: @NachoF - as you wish, example added.

Answer (score 4):

The MetaData "buddy" class is exactly what this is for.   The validation is created once but can be used on both the model and the viewmodel classes:

```
public class PersonMetaData
{
  [Required] 
  public string Name {get; set;}  

  [Required] 
  public string LastName {get; set;} 
}

[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetaData))]
public class Person
{
  public string Name {get; set;}  
  public string LastName {get; set;} 
}

[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetaData))]
public class PersonFormViewModel 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}  
  public string LastName {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: BUt what are the perforamnce implications in passing an entire Business Class into a View and using as a ViewModel to gernerate editable data and re submitting it back to the Controller and passing it into the ORM x 1000 views a minute VS using a ViewModel specific to the view and passing that model into the Business to get transformed into the correct Data. Data will always be busy but how do buddy classes affect overhead for busy servers in the viewEngine? Sure it is flippin easy but thrashing a server is also easy because we don't realise the implications of these actions.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by RPM1984, and nice code sample.

My view is still that using Variant 2 from the start is a pragmatic balance between productivity and structure, but you always have to be willing to move to Variant 3 in some cases, so I advocate a mix of the two approaches where logical. Patterns & Practices however recommend always doing Variant 3 as it is the ideal separation of concerns etc, and it avoids you using two approaches in the same solution which some people don't like and many customers I work with pick Variant 3 and run with that for all models.

I think the key is what RPM1984 said - reusing your business entities inside your View Models is useful for the sake of reusing the validation, but do bear in mind that often your business logic needs to do different validation too (e.g. checking the record doesn't already exist). If you use Variant 3 it empowers you to focus your View Model validation purely on the needs of your views (at the expense of a little extra effort) but you will always need some kind of business logic validation too.

Comment: you should consider to use a comment instead of an Answer, or the upvote, if you have nothing new to say.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you always pass viewmodels to your view and your domain models are not exposed to the end user through views then i don't see any need for validating domain model itself. For example if you receive PersonViewModel from view through form post you will transform it to Person Model (perhaps through automapper etc.) only if PersonViewModel is valid itself. So i believe that input validations should stay with the view models because they are the one that are bound to input.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your ViewModel will contain a reference to your Model - a ViewModel is only necessary if you need to display additional information in your view that isn't available in your Model, there is no need to replicate the data already present.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you pass your business model objects down to the view when you dont need extra info that is not contained in the business object itself?

Comment: Correct, for example here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx Scott Guthrie passes his Person type containing the data annotations to his view in the controller.

Comment: I've just read the article that you have linked, and can't see anywhere where Jimmy says 'you should not send your business models to your views'. In fact the word 'not' doesn't appear anywhere in the article and Jimmy states 'Of course, many of these opinions are only really valid in the constraints of our project' and 'these opinions may or may not apply to the project you work on.  Again, patterns are all about tradeoffs, benefits and liabilities'

Comment: Well he says "we never pass an Domain Model entity straight into the view.".... my question is still... given that i DO want to use this approach.. where should the validation go?

Comment: The link that you have added (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) backs up my suggestion as described in Variant 2: Container View Model - 'Overall, this is my personal favourite as it provides flexibility and future proofing for little extra effort over and above Variant 1'. If you really want to go with the 'utopia practice' of Variant 3, then I would use HitLikeAHammer's approach.