# Removing data annotation from model and placing them in separate class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I am working on an asp.net mvc application and I was asked to remove the data annotations from my models and put them in a separate class.The first thing that came to my mind was to use the Fluent API for this.

After a bit of research I realised that the Fluent API can only be used in the code first approach , so I am left with no clue with how I should solve this problem.

I am using the database first approach.

This is how one of my models looks like:

```
public class BookModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}" , ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:c}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string BookUrl { get; set; }
}
```

So can anyone point me in the right direction in order to solve my problem?

Comment: are annotations used for validation only? also is it WPF / Silverlight application?

Comment: is is an asp.net MVC application and yes so far I was asked to only validate but I am not sure what I will be asked to do in the future

Comment: why do you want to remove annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the concept of Buddy Classes

[Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)

[Model validation 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553380/where-do-you-put-your-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/6553406#6553406)

Answer (score 1):

You can create ViewModel classes that will (only) represent each view. And you can add your validation logic on them.

If you want to keep your class look clean, and move validation logic in a separate class, than you can have a partial class to hold data annotations, or a [validation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)