# Update Model From Database (Database First)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 VS2010 with EF4.1, I have created my DB using SQL Server and I import it to the MVC3 Web Application.

I have a challenge here, when I come to Update Model from Database I do lost all my models files modifications, for example if I'm using attributes in some models for validation or so all that is overwritten with the new model properties.

Is there anyway to Update Model from Database without losing models' information?

OR

where should I define validation on my models instead of using the models' files directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** As this is still relatively popular, I have created a blog post on this.

http://jnye.co/Posts/19/adding-validation-to-models-created-by-entity-framework-database-first-c

If you want to validate your models, and not use viewModels, use partial classes to define validation attributes. For example:

Say you have a model like

```
public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you wanted to put a string length validator on it you would need to create a partial class and utilise the `MetadataTypeAttribute` (this lives in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)

The following classes should be defined in their own separate file, **NOT** put in the same file as your auto generated models.

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User {
}
```

You then define your validation in the `UserMetadata` class as follows

```
public class UserMetadata{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

EDIT

I just found this article which explains the solution in a little more detail
http://themonitoringguy.com/tips-tricks/validating-microsoft-entity-framework-objects-c-mvc/

Comment: So every time the model regenerated I have to go back for each file and redefine my [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof()] attribute. Thank you @NinjaNye but this is not practical for me.

Comment: No, you will only need to define validation for a new property, which you will have to do anyway.  The partial class and metadata class will not get overwritten or replaced

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this bit clearer, define your partial class and metadata class in a separate file, NOT in the auto generated file. I will update my answer

Comment: You're missing a closing ) on [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(UserMetadata)]

Comment: Good spot @DannyCullen, this is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

No, the files will be regenerated every time.

All the classes are defined as partial so you can easily add DataAnnotations using the `MetadataTypeAttribute`.

Let's say you have a `User` class defined as follow:

```
public partial class User {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Create a `IUser` interface

```
public interface IUser {
   [Required]
   [DisplayName("User name")]
   string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And then extend the `User` class to specify that `IUser` will be used as metadata.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IUser))]
public partial class User {} //Empty class body
```

Comment: Thank you Bertand, you and @NinjaNye have provided a great help.

Comment: Is MetadataType here any different than just using the `:` keyword to extend the interface?

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of any designer is: It it generates any code you can't modify it because it will be completely deleted next time you update anything in the designer.

All generated classes are partial so you can create your own partial part and put your custom logic there. You obviously can't add attributes to properties defined in auto generated part. In case of data annotations it is possible either through [buddy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128303/how-to-add-validation-to-my-pocotemplate-classes/5128373#5128373) or by custom T4 template which will contain your own logic to decide which data annotation should be added during code generation. Both scenarios are mostly considered as a bad practice because you should have separate view model per view with validation needed exactly for that view.

Answer (score 1):

Check the namespace of the MainClass is same as Partial, and have the same Attributes. That is my solution.

example:

Metadata: Create this everywhere u want

```
public class FormMetadata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsEnable { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int CompanieId { get; set; }
    public string RegularExpression { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

MainClass

```
namespace Transactions.Model
{
  public partial class Form
  {
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
      public Form()
      {
          this.Fields = new HashSet<Field>();
      }  
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public Nullable<bool> IsEnable { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
      public int CompanieId { get; set; }
      public string RegularExpression { get; set; }
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
      public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Partial To Use the MetadataType

```
namespace Transactions.Model
{
    [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(FormMetadata))]
    public partial class Form
    {
    }
}
```

If you have problems to Create a Class Partial in the same NameSpace? Don't worry:

1. Create a Folder
2. Create the Class Partial in this folder
3. Change Namespace at the same of MainClass