# Validation attributes in external file using MetadataTypeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation

I let VS create my model from existing SQL tables using EF 4.3.1. Because the DB tables are not final and may change I don't want to set the validation attributes directly into the model file because it gets overwritten when I update the model.

I want to use the MetadataTypeAttribute approach described here: 
[Update Model From Database (Database First)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758525/update-model-from-database-database-first)

So I created an external file containing this class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PDB.Models
{
    [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(t_scriptingMetadata))]
    public partial class t_scripting
    {
    }

    public class t_scriptingMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public int platform {get; set;}

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Projectname {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get these errors in VS:

- Duplicate EdmEntityTypeAttribute attribute
- Duplicate Serializable attribute
- Duplicate DataContractAttribute attribute

My model that has been generated by VS has exactly these attributes the error message mentions:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="CAWI_STDMGTModel", Name="t_scripting")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class t_scripting : EntityObject
{
    //...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your t_scriptingMetadata class have to be into t_scripting</strike> not necessarily

```
    [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(t_scriptingMetadata))] 
public partial class t_scripting 
{ 
  public class t_scriptingMetadata 
  { 
     [Required] 
     public int platform {get; set;} 

     [Required] 
     [StringLength(20)] 
     public string Projectname {get; set;} 
  } 
}
```

And both partial classes must have same namespace.
Hope this help.
Regards

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately that did not change anything, i.e. still the same errors.

Comment: According to this [link](http://themonitoringguy.com/tips-tricks/validating-microsoft-entity-framework-objects-c-mvc/) the classes do not have to be into each other.

Comment: Your right. I'm in a mistake. recently edit the post. Are partial classes in the same namespace?

Comment: Can you upload a project sample with that?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6f7jnectz6urxff/stackOverflow.zip) it is. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: It´s nothing. Try do a Clean Solution and then rebuild. This work for me.

Comment: What do you mean? This compiles for you? When I press F6 to build I get three errors.

Comment: Forget it, I have found the problem. I had a table in my model that actually is a view containing fields from another table that was also in my model. Thank for your help.

Comment: Ok. Clean is a option of visual studio. Right click in solution->Clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I had a table in my model that actually is a view containing fields from another table that was also in my model. So the error messages were indeed right. Thank for your help, vfabre!