# Automatic Model Validation When Generating the Models using Entity Framework Database First Approach

Tags: entity-framework

Consider the following property UserName of a Model Class. You can see that the validation criteria are added over it manually.

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 6)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Now again consider the following code:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

The same property without the validators. Now when I am generating the model class using Entity Framework Database first approach I am getting the later result (means a property without having validators). But in the database there are constraints added over each attribute.

So is there any tool/way that I can use those constraints and generate the model class having properties like shown in code 1 (that is property with validators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no ready to use tool which would add these attributes for you. You can modify T4 template to create these attributes for you but for that you need to understand how EF metadata are stored. You can add attributes yourselves [manually in buddy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128303/how-to-add-validation-to-my-pocotemplate-classes/5128373#5128373).