# Required Model Validation Generating the Models using Entity Framework Database First Approach

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

In continuation with the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7316202/4824728), even with EF 6, I am having issues generating the [Required] Data Annotation for certain fields for a model autogenerated from Database Table. Am I missing something or is it still not supported? The DB fields that I am looking at are "NOT NULL". Any help will be appreciated! I have too many tables and fields to look at and automating this process via Entity framework will be nice to have!